# MacOS Accessibility API not working after change in code and new build (Xcode/Swift simulating keyboard input)

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, accessibility

I found this code and have been using for an app that pastes measurements from a bluetooth laser distance measurement device to the focused application.

When I run it for the first time MacOS prompts me to allow it to use the accessibility features and I allow it. It then works as suspected.
But if I change something in the code and recompile it, it doesn't work any longer. I then first have to delete my app from Preferences/Security/Privacy/Accessebility and run it again. Then it asked again for permission and works.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? I'm quite a beginner and only started to code again because I needed a Mac app for that device.

```
func pasteMatchStyle() {
    /*Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40096457/swift-macos-how-to-paste-into-another-application?noredirect=1&lq=1
    */
    
    let event1 = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: 0x09, keyDown: true) // opt-shft-cmd-v down
    event1?.flags = [CGEventFlags.maskCommand, CGEventFlags.maskShift, CGEventFlags.maskAlternate]
    event1?.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap)
    
    let event2 = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: 0x09, keyDown: false) // opt-shf-cmd-v up
    event2?.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not as I have no problem with the prompt popping up on the first run.

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you just uncheck and re-check the permissions box, and then re-run your app.

Accessibility permissions only apply to the app that was approved, but you've built a new version that the system has identified as different (read: untrusted), *but that old version is still approved*, so the box stays checked.

Comment: Thanks, that also works but it doesn't seem to be a good user experience. Would it change it's behaviour if I sign it with a developer acccount? 
I personally use apps, that don't require to me to check and uncheck it every time they get an update.

Comment: Yes; in my experience, signing an app with an Apple developer account lets it keeps its permissions as long as the code signature’s „Team Identifier“ stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have been there wrapping my head around spending a lot of times.
Eventually, I sorted it out and hopefully it could the same problem you encountered.

You may have not set up `App Sandbox` on a macOS app.

```
Go to project setting -> Signing & Capabilities -> + Capability -> Add App Sandbox.
```

To look like this on `Signing & Capability` tab in Xcode project :

[image]

(It shouldn't matter which options are checked on/off)

too late to the party, but It works for me now at least in 2023.

I guess it might be the slightly different problem you were running into, 
but I hope it may help other devs deal with the problem.